# How to create a pattern to filter out python test files

Tags: python, regex

I have a bash script to execute my python tests and I would like to filter all test cases that have NOT_DONE in them

This is what I tried

```
python3 -m unittest discover -s ${FOLDER} -p 'test_((?!NOT_DONE).)*_ALL.py'
```

Input example :

`test_word_NOT_DONE_more_words_alot_more_words_ALL.py` <- This test shouldn't be executed

But this one should :

```
test_word_more_words_alot_more_words_ALL.py
```

Comment: Why not just use a glob pattern on all the files, import them, and then set a variable for `NOT_DONE = True` That way, you can skip incomplete tests. You can do `var = importlib.import_module(some_path); if getattr(var, 'NOT_DONE', False):    pass`

Comment: Do you have a Bash solution?

Comment: I don't recommend it, but sure. The problem is that pattern negation doesn't work properly in the `--pattern` keyword.

`find !(*NOT_DONE*)` will work, but not with the pattern keyword. Of course, a much better solution would be to include a pattern in your finished files, or to use a Python-based solution.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Do you have a more complete example of the first comment?

Comment: I'll post two complete solutions below.

Answer (score 2):

**Path Solution**

Directory Structure

```
unittesting/
    launcher.py
    tests/
        __init__.py
        test_finished.py
        test_NOT_DONE.py
        folder/
            __init__.py
            test_finished2.py
            test_NOT_DONE2.py
```

Inside each test file is `print(__file__)`, nested under a TestCase method. Therefore, only if the module is imported and the test cases run, will it be executed.

Code:

```
import importlib
import os
import sys
import unittest


HOME = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, 'tests')


def check_file(file):
    '''Check if file is test'''

    return all((
        'NOT_DONE' not in file,
        file.endswith('.py'),
        file != '__init__.py'
    ))


def find_paths(home=HOME):
    '''Find all paths'''

    os.chdir(HOME)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('tests'):
        for file in files:
            if check_file(file):
                if root != 'tests':
                    yield os.path.join(root[len('tests/'):], file)
                else:
                    yield file

def normalize(path):
    '''Normalize path to dotted name'''

    path = os.path.splitext(path)[0]
    unix = path.replace('/', '.')
    return unix.replace('\\', '.')


def tests(paths=None):
    '''Load and run tests'''

    if paths is None:
        paths = map(normalize, find_paths())
    modules = (importlib.import_module(i) for i in paths)

    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    for module in modules:
        tests = loader.loadTestsFromModule(module)
        suite.addTests(tests)

    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(suite)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tests()
```

As you can see, this gets unwieldly quickly, and very hard to manage. There's a simpler way. It runs, however.

```
$ python /home/alex/git/unittesting/launcher.py
tests/test_finished.pyc
.tests/folder/test_finished2.pyc
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

**Pythonic Solution**

Inside each of my files that is not complete, I put the variable `NOT_DONE = True`, and each of my classes has a decorator `skipif`.

Directory Structure

```
unittesting/
    launcher.py
    tests/
        __init__.py
        test1.py
        test2.py
        folder/
            __init__.py
            test3.py
            test4.py
```

In this example, `test2` and `test4` have `NOT_DONE = True`, while `test1` and `test3` have `NOT_DONE = False`.

An example file is as follows:

```
import unittest

NOT_DONE = False

# CASES
# -----


@unittest.skipIf(NOT_DONE, 'Reason')
class TestPrint(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_print(self):
        print(__file__)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Now, to run I simply do:

```
$ python -m unittest discover tests
tests/test1.py
tests/folder/test3.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.000s

OK (skipped=2)
```

**Best Approach**

Unfinished unittests should have a `unittest.skipIf(True, 'Unfinished')` line, so you get control not only at the module level, but also at the class or even method level. In the following example, I have one, finished unittest and one unfinished unittest. Running the example skips the first unittest, but runs the rest of the module.

```
import unittest

# CASES
# -----


@unittest.skipIf(True, 'Not Finished')
class TestPrint(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_print(self):
        print(__file__)


class TestPrinting(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_print(self):
        print(__file__)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: I need to use regex because the *ALL* part can change too

Comment: @Lorac, just change the path-based solution to use your own filter, or standardize the names.

Comment: `os.path.dirname(__file__)` returns nothing empty string

Comment: @Lorac, whoopsy small typo. Should use `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`

Fixing now.

Comment: `product_type = sys.argv[1]
    if product_type == 'something':
        prog = re.compile("test_.*(_SOME|_ALL).py")
        tests(regex=prog)`

I'm trying to execute some tests that depends on the argument given in command line